# how to call pkill in c program without using "system() library function"

Tags: c, linux

In the below program, I've used system library function to execute "pkill" command. Is there any system call available for pkill(Because PID is unknown). I don't want to use "system" library function. Please let me know how to do it

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
        char test[1024] = "pkill -15 radio";
        system(test);
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is no such system call. However, the "/proc" file system has information about all running processes. You can write a program that goes through all "/proc/***/status" files (where "***" is the PID), check the "Name" line, and kill all processes that match.

Answer (score 1):

The system call for sending signals to processes is [kill](https://linux.die.net/man/3/kill); however, you need the process id for. If you intend to launch the program to be killed from within your application, too, use [fork](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) together with one of the [exec-functions](https://linux.die.net/man/3/execl) and you have it. Otherwise, you will most likely have to iterate over the `/proc/*` subdirectories.